# Doctrine DBAL Params in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to filter my Doctrine DABL MySQL query using parameters in where clause:

$this->dbConn refers to doctrine db connection.

$this->tableName holds the correct table name.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE `category` = 'armor' AND ? != ?";
$stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare($sql);
```

$filterKey and $filterVal contain correct values.

```
$params = [
    $this->dbConn->quoteIdentifier($filterKey),
    $this->dbConn->quote($filterVal)
];

$stmt = $this->dbConn->executeQuery($sql, $params, [\PDO::PARAM_STR, \PDO::PARAM_STR]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

$result contains rows where $filterKey == $filterVal opposed to expected

Following also does not works

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE `category` = 'armor' AND :filterKey != :filterVal";
$stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue('filterKey', $this->dbConn->quoteIdentifier($filterKey), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('filterVal', $this->dbConn->quote($filterVal), \PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

$result contains rows where $filterKey == $filterVal opposed to expected

Am I missing something basic here?
BTW, I'm trying not to use queryBuilder.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are even executing the statement?  As far as I know you can't use parameters for column names so I'm surprised you are not getting an error.

Comment: Yes, its executing and Im obtaining results, as I said, ignoring the parameterized section of the where clause. No errors at all. I wonder why is there a quoteIdentifier method if you can't parametrize column names.

Comment: Have you tried with Named parameters?

Comment: Second example uses named parameters.

Comment: Just guessing, change != to <>

Comment: Already tried. I think that as you said in the first comment, it may not be possible to parameterize column names.

Comment: By the way, quote and quateIdentifiers are intended to be used when building raw sql strings.  They serve no purpose when using prepared statements.